# How to start recording samples when a specific tone frequency is detected?

Tags: python

I have implemented a similar method that can be seen in this repo https://github.com/rraval/pied-piper/blob/master/decode.py

My problem is that I don't understand how to properly analyze the following incoming audio signal that I play and record on receiver end.

[image]

This is a wav fle that I generated programatically and then added some noise with the help of audacity. This audio signal starts with a START tone with a frequency of 400 Hz and ends with a 500 Hz tone, in between are tones (in this case 8) with frequencies between 10kHz-20kHz, so pretty far away from START / STOP frequencies.

I want to play this audio and capture it in a receiver via recording. The recording is done continuously until START is detected and STOP is detected. So the Receiver doesn't really know when the audio starts. I have previously managed to decode a wav file when I directly read the wav file that I generated, without recording it.

So how exactly do I interpret the exact moment a tone of START frequency is recorded, keep recording until the STOP tone is recorded and then end up with a nump array or even a wav file that I can work with?

Some values that are known to the receiver:

```
Sampling Rate: 44100 Hz
Tone length: 0.1s (can be changed)
Silence (noise) length: 0.1s (can be changed)
START and END tone frequencies: i.e. 400 and 500 Hz
```

These values indicate a window size of 4410 samples, see frame_rate calculation below, where I tried to half the window whilst recording.

Before beginning and after end I added 0.5s of silence (noise) just so audacity doesn't cut off some audio samples

I've debugged a little bit to see when and if I ever enter a chunk where the START / STOP frequency is, but it is super unreliable. I think it's just pure luck as the dominant_frequency is calculated.

The match function has a deviance of about 50Hz, just in case. I record with sounddevice.

```
stop_sync_freq = 500
start_sync_freq = 400
fs = 44100
tone_len = 0.1
silence_len = 0.1

def get_dominant_frequency(data_chunk):
    w = np.fft.fft(data_chunk)
    frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(len(data_chunk))

    peak_coeff = np.argmax(np.abs(w))
    peak_freq = frequencies[peak_coeff]
    return abs(peak_freq * fs


def record_audio():
    # devices = sd.query_devices()
    frame_rate = int(round(tone_len / 2 * fs))

    in_window = False
    audio_packet = []

    while True:
        data_input = sd.rec(frames=frame_rate, samplerate=fs, channels=1)
        sd.wait()

        if not data_input.size > 0:
            continue

        dominant_frequency = get_dominant_frequency(data_input)
        print(dominant_frequency)

        if in_window and match(dominant_frequency, stop_sync_freq):
            # End - Stop freq
            in_window = False
            break
        elif in_window:
            audio_packet.append(dominant_frequency)
        elif match(dominant_frequency, start_sync_freq):
            # Start - Start freq
            in_window = True


record_audio()
```

Comment: If the wave is always as in your example, the problem seems 'how to start recording when the amplitude is more than zero' instead which is easier. Anyway, using recording for that purpose seems a little bit complicated : what you want to do is simply trimming the existing file. Why not load it into a buffer and resize it quietly from there ?

Comment: @dspr The wave can be longer, shorter, but the starting and ending is always the same. The amplitude of the important parts is always around "1". So I guess it might be an option to check when that is the case and then cut off any information prior to that scenario, and then the same at the end? But then I don't see the point of a synchronization, unless I want to make sure that it is indeed a message that is being sent and not some random ambient sound that triggered the start.

Comment: For the end, because there are some silences between sounds, doing as for start is not possible. If you would work with a buffer instead of a kind of stream, I would suggest doing the same but backward and starting from the end.

Comment: @dspr And just for clarification, I want to explicitly send it over sound and capture it with a microphone and not trim the original file itself, because it could be different clients that do this.

Comment: Well, this is a lot more complicated since you're forced to work in real time. Theoretically, you need a callback from the sound system to do that. Within that callback you should analyse the signal, start capturing all samples in an array once you encountered the start signal and until you reach the end signal. After that, you can do what you want with the captured data.